# Laravel Mix - JS as ES2016

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

By default *(for production)*, Laravel Mix converts JS to ES5. I would like to be able to manage it and turn it off as needed. Here are my files:

**webpack.mix.js:**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.disableNotifications();
mix.setPublicPath('./');

mix.js([
  '_dev/js/Core.js'
], 'public/dist/js/scripts.js');
```

**_dev/js/Core.js:**

```
class Core {

  constructor()
  {
    console.log('Hello World!');
  }

}

new Core();
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "chrome 60",
    "firefox 55",
    "safari 11"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0"
  }
}
```

Can I change the preset in some way? Ideally, Babel would take **browserslist** into consideration and convert JS based on them. For example, if I have an IE11 there is ES2015, if not ES2016.

Autoprefixer at Laravel Mix supports **browserslist** and works sensational!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mix.inProduction()` to see what environment you're on. Below is an example that could give you a starting point.

```js
...

const isProduction = mix.inProduction();

// Set some default settings globlal to both production and development
let configuration = {};

// Place your production settings inside here
configuration.production: {};

// Place your development settings inside here
configuration.development: {}; 

if ( isProduction   ) return configuration.production;

if ( ! isProduction ) return configuration.developent;
```